# Query using 3 tables of database

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am working on queries with oracle 10g database.
I am facing a certain problem.It is as follow :

I am having say 3 tables say table1,table2,table3.

Now in table1 suppose i have 2 columns myid,id.

In table2 suppose i have 2 columns table2id,table2name.

In table3 suppose i have 2 columns table3id,table3name.

Now i want myid,id,name from tables which have a particular myid,say X.

Example : 
Say table 1 is having 3 entries :

```
1 11
2 11
3 13
```

Table 2 as follow :

```
11 John
12 Michael
```

Table 3 as follow :

```
13 Steve
```

Then here answer will be :

```
1 11 John
2 11 John
3 13 Steve
```

How to do it ?

Comment: So what is your particular problem? Do you know how to write SQL statements? If so, what have you tried, where did you fail?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I know to write sql statements.But Sadly Join ,Union and all is my weaker section.

Comment: Well, SQL Statements are all about joins. If you say joins are your weakness, then you don't know SQL. I think it would not be much use, if we gave you a complete solution here. You should learn about joins by reading about them and trying yourself. Try to write the statement on your own and come back with something you tried to get our advice on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Bellow:

```
SELECT table1.myid, table1.id,table2.name as name

FROM table1

INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id

UNION 

SELECT table1.myid, table1.id,table3.name as name

FROM table1

INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table1.id;
```

Comment: What if say i have one more table 4 and i want its records along with this,mapping with first table on basis of myid

Comment: You need to add one more union. Like
SELECT table1.myid, table1.id,table4.name as name

FROM table1

INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.id = table1.id;

Answer (score 0):

Join the three tables and then restrict the search. Check oracle's site: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html